# Framework7: how to get HTML of all pages?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm using [Framework7](https://framework7.io/) which is great. I need to parse innerHTML of all of my pages in runtime. How can I obtain HTML for page different than a current one?
I was trying to make use of `router`, `routes` and `page` API's but with no luck.

To sum things up: I don't want to load different pages in the view, I want to load them in a variable to make some further processing.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in-build ajax:

```js
Framework7.request.get('somepage.html').then((res) => {  
  console.log(res.data);
});
```

You can also refer to the [docs](https://framework7.io/docs/request.html) for further investigations